# When do we need to "require 'rubygems'"?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

This is related to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179797/how-to-use-rubytorrent-or-other-gems

I thought RubyGems is a package manager, similar to apt-get on Ubuntu...

So when do we need to `require 'rubygems'` in our code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `require 'rubygems'` when you are using a gem that you installed with Rubygems. The reason is that Ruby uses Rubygems to determine the path of the gem that Rubygems installed. (is unable to locate the gem you want to use)

Alternatively, you can pass the `-rubygems` flag when you invoke your script, or set `export RUBYOPT=rubygems` in your profile (`~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`) which is basically the same as the flag, except it is implicit.

On 1.9, rubygems is required implicilty, and you shouldn't have to do that.

Here are some docs about it http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3

Note: Some have built solutions (zozo and faster_rubygems) to avoid Rubygems overhead http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/212463

Comment: docs.rubygems.org seems to be dead. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130825010804/http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3) is an archive of docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3 . Or, here are also some docs at http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/ .